# Converting Number format

Tags: matlab, formatting

I have problem understanding the numbers produced by Matlab. 
What does the e mean? And how can i convert those numbers to int? 
This is the answer for a matrix x=[x1, x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]

```
ans =

  1.0e+004 *

   -0.0000
   -0.6340
   -0.3660
   -0.8966
    0.6340
    1.0000
   -0.7321
    0.6340
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1.0e+004` means `1.0*10^4`.

Casting works using int32(x), depending on your target accuracy you can also use int16(x) or int64(x). Check out the documentation http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/int32.html

Rounding is also done.